# how to set the TimeZone

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am trying set the time zone in ScheduleRequest its not working but automation is scheduled   timezone is not set  its taking default time zone 
this is my code

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>*****</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">    
    <Action>start</Action>
    <Schedule>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Recurrence xsi:type="q1:DailyRecurrence" xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>Interval</q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>
            <q1:DayInterval>1</q1:DayInterval>
        </Recurrence>
        <RecurrenceType>Daily</RecurrenceType>
        <RecurrenceRangeType>EndAfter</RecurrenceRangeType>
       <StartDateTime>2018-02-27T09:00:00-06:30</StartDateTime>
        <TimeZone>(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</TimeZone>

        <Occurrences>1</Occurrences>
    </Schedule>
    <Interactions>
        <Interaction xsi:type="q2:Automation" xmlns:q2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <q2:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <q2:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
             <q2:CustomerKey>ea5cb858-80fa-dd28-b3c3-d182682d9c4e</q2:CustomerKey>
        </Interaction>
    </Interactions>
</ScheduleRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: @Tushar Sharma how to set the TimeZone in the  above code please help me

Answer (score 1):

timezone value is an int.  this page as a list of values - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/timezone.htm